# Testing workflow for small (i.e. one person) design in SystemVerilog

Tags: unit-testing, fpga, system-verilog, hdl, uvm

I started implementing design in SystemVerilog but I'm a bit lost as far as testing is concerned. I tried to use straightforward SystemVerilog for verification but it seems limited:

- The errors are spotted by going through the log (even `$error` and `assert` don't stop simulation) so they can be easily missed.
- I cannot (?) run all the tests as Vivado allows to use only one as active
- I could put everything in single test simulation but waveform for debugging seems too long as it mixes various tests.
- I can try to create my own framework but it sounds like reinventing the wheel which is bad idea.

I know of [SVUnit](https://github.com/nosnhojn/svunit-code) but it seems to work with expensive simulators, not xsim I have license for. I'm trying to look at UVM but I'm not sure if the investment of time is worth it.

What would be a good test workflow for SV for person coming from software (drivers) for personal, one-person, FPGA project?

Comment: What does "I cannot run all tests" exactly mean? It depends on how you define tests.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Vivado Simulator doesn't support the constructs required for UVM.

Comment: Does xsim have a TCL (or any other command line scripting interface)?

Comment: To close votes: since many solutions require many thousands $ tools I don't see it any more opinion based then [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577262/development-workflow-for-small-team) [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492169/git-workflow-for-small-web-team).

Comment: @TudorTimi I think you are right that it doesn't support UVM. I don't know if it supports TCL - I think so. By 'run all tests' I mean that after a single click all testsuite is run and I get result that, for example, 7/10 tests passed, where each test is possibly separate config.

Comment: @MaciejPiechotka If you ask for a free unit testing solution for SystemVerilog which provides your required features rather than a "good test workflow" it wouldn't be opinion-based.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running all tests isn't usually done in one simulator invocation. This is handled as multiple invocations by a different tool, which usually does more (distribute jobs across a compute farm, centralizes status, etc.).

Determining whether a test passed or failed is usually done by inspecting the log file. If an error was detected, it should show up in the log and you can grep for it. The simulator's exit code isn't used for this, since non-zero exit codes mean that something was wrong with the tool invocation, not with the simulation itself.

In your case, since you only have the simulator available you have to build a lot of the infrastructure. You'll need a script that can run a single test and can determine if it was a PASS or a FAIL (via grep, Perl, etc.). You can then define another script that loops over all of your tests, calls the previous script and computes a summary.

Comment: @MaciejPiechotka There are some more fine points here relating to avoiding recompiles between test runs, which is partly the reason why I asked if your tool supports TCL. It seems, though, that you already have some SystemVerilog tests. For 10 tests it doesn't really make sense to optimize here, but if you run, for example, 1000 tests, the time wasted on recompiling becomes more significant.

Comment: Thanks - I assumed that such tools are ready as in non-HDL language world and there is no point in reinventing the wheel. It looks like that's not the case.

Comment: @MaciejPiechotka They exist, but they're either proprietary or commercial tools. Where I work, for example, we had an in-house tool for test run management, but we ditched it for a paid tool.

Comment: @MaciejPiechotka This is something that could become a nice open source project, but I don't know if there's interest for this.

Answer (score 3):

The **free and open source** [VUnit](http://vunit.github.io/index.html) provides a single click (= single command) solution that will find your test suites and test cases, (re)compile what's needed (no recompiles between tests), run the simulations and then present the pass/fail result.

[image: VUnit with SystemVerilog]

VUnit started as a VHDL unit testing framework but since much of the top-level automation is language agnostic it was updated to also support SystemVerilog. The difference between the VHDL and SV support is that VUnit provides a number of testbench support packages for VHDL which you don't find for SV. On the other hand, some of that functionality is already part of SV.

Find out the very basics [here](http://vunit.github.io/user_guide.html). The UART example above can be found in the examples [directory](https://github.com/VUnit/vunit/tree/master/examples).

VUnit supports simulators from Mentor, Aldec and Cadence and also the open source GHDL. It doesn't support Vivado today but it's being [discussed](https://github.com/VUnit/vunit/issues/209). However, you can use the **free ModelSim Altera Edition**.

Disclaimer: I'm one of the authors for VUnit.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried VUnit? If you are interested to run UVM, we do have a port of UVM base class that runs on free Modelsim (With some limitations such as no randomisation, coverage, SVA etc.) as part of Go2UVM (www.go2uvm.org).

Regards
Srini